puppeteer macos Error: Failed to launch the browser process
I use puppeteer for run a chrome profile in local but when open chrome then show error like this:
file:///Users/cheng/Workspace/web3/puppeteer/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/esm/launch.js:301
                reject(new Error([
                       ^

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting

    at ChildProcess.onClose (file:///Users/cheng/Workspace/web3/puppeteer/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/esm/launch.js:301:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)

Node.js v21.7.1

This is my code:
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

(async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      executablePath: "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome",
      args: [
         '--user-data-dir=/Users/cheng/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome',
         '--profile-directory=Profile 7',
         '--no-sandbox',
         '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
      ],

   });
   const page = await browser.newPage();

   await page.goto('https://developer.chrome.com/');

   await page.setViewport({ width: 1080, height: 1024 });


})();



Does this answer your question? Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer

I am having the same issue running it in heroku. However, it only happens periodically. Any luck?
